# Call same events from different modules in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have two different modules and with installing that modules i am creating two events, names are different, event's trigger is same (i.e. `admin/model/customer/customer/addCustomer/after`) and action are also different in **OpenCart 2.3.**

My Problem is when i add the customer from admin side it  executs only for first module. It does not execute for second module.

if i uninstall the first module and add the customer then event for my second module is working fine,

I want to execute some code from two different modules when customer will be added by administrator,

Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue in my event call. Kindly check that in your custom event function you are not returning anything after function call.
If you are returning it anything it will come out from the event logic and will not run your or any other module's event.
So kindly comment any return done in your function and test.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay , let me try this . . .

Answer (score 2):

Never return values incase you are calling any CURL or third party API.
instead of returning values you can store it in any global variables and go ahead.